# Replacing a pandas DataFrame value with np.nan when the values ends with '_h'

Tags: python, pandas

Below is the code that I have been working with to replace some values with np.NaN.  My issue is how to replace'47614750_h' at index 111 with np.NaN.  I can do this directly with drop_list, however, I need to iterate this with different values ending in '_h' over many files and would like to do this automatically.
I have tried some searches on regex as it seems the way to go, but could not find what i needed.

```
drop_list = ['dash_code', 'SONIC WELD']

df_clean.replace(drop_list, np.NaN).tail(10)

    DASH_CODE     Name                          Quantity
107 1011567      .156 MALE BULLET TERM INSUL    1.0
108 102066901     .032 X .187 FEMALE Q.D. TERM. 1.0
109 105137901     TERM,RING,10-12AWG,INSULATED  1.0
110 101919701     1/4 RING TERM INSUL           2.0
111 47614750001_h HARNESS, MAIN, AC, LIO        1.0
112 NaN           NaN                           19.0
113 7685          5/16 RING TERM INSUL.         1.0
114 102521601     CLIP,HARNESS                  2.0
115 47614808001   CAP, RESISTOR, TERMINATION    1.0
116 103749801     RECPT, DEUTSCH, DTM04-4P      1.0
```

Comment: Here is a better picture of my dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have been able to use both solutions and these solutions answer other unrelated questions that I had.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.Series.apply` for this with a lambda:

```
df['DASH_CODE'] = df['DASH_CODE'].apply(lambda x: np.NaN if x.endswith('_h') else x)
```

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas-series-apply):

> Invoke function on values of Series. Can be ufunc (a NumPy function
>   that applies to the entire Series) or a Python function that only
>   works on single values

Answer (score 2):

It may be faster to try to convert all the rows to float using [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
In [11]: pd.to_numeric(df.DASH_CODE, errors='coerce')
Out[11]:
0    1.011567e+06
1    1.020669e+08
2    1.051379e+08
3    1.019197e+08
4             NaN
5             NaN
6    7.685000e+03
7    1.025216e+08
8    4.761481e+10
9    1.037498e+08
Name: DASH_CODE, dtype: float64

In [12]: df["DASH_CODE"] = pd.to_numeric(df["DASH_CODE"], errors='coerce')
```